# Does executing EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager() reutrn new instance each time?

Tags: java, jpa

Does executing EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager() reutrn new instance each time? or it returns the cached copy of the same EntityManager each time?

Answer (score 2):

The [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html#createEntityManager%28%29) is unambiguous:

> Create a new application-managed
>   EntityManager. This method returns a
>   new EntityManager instance each time
>   it is invoked.

Comment: if so then why executing below lines throw EntityExistsExecption
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("basicPU"); 
Item item = new Item();
 for (int i = 0 ; i<10; i++){ 
     em = emf.createEntityManager(); 
     em.persist(item)
 } 


But executing below lines adds new record to database...
 
Item item = new Item();
 for (int i = 0 ; i<10; i++){ 
     emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("basicPU"); 
     em = emf.createEntityManager(); 
     em.persist(item)
 }

Comment: @Digambar: I have no idea. That's a different question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

EntityManagerFactory returns new instance of EntityManager on each call to EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().

If you execute...

```
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("basicPU");
 for (int i = 0 ; i<10; i++){
     System.out.println(em = emf.createEntityManager());
 }
```

It Prints:

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@18105e8
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@9bad5a
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@91f005
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@1250ff2
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@3a0ab1
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@940f82
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@864e43
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@17c2891
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@4b82d2
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@179d854
```

Comment: That doesn't prove anything, that just shows that your particular JPA implementation and environment and test returns a new instance each time.

Comment: I think it proves that executing EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager() returns new instance of EntityManager on each call, does not returns some cached EntityManager Object.

Comment: No, it proves it *just for your test*, it proves nothing about what other implementations or environments would do.

Answer (score 0):

To second skaffman's answer, here is an extract of the JPA 1.0 specification:

> #### 5.9.2 Provider Responsibilities
>
> The Provider has no knowledge of the
>   distinction between transaction-scoped
>   and extended persistence contexts. It
>   provides entity managers to the
>   container when requested and registers
>   for synchronization notifications for
>   the transaction.
>
> - **When `EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager`
>     is invoked, the provider must create
>     and return a new entity manager**. If
>     a JTA transaction is active, the
>     provider must register for
>     synchronization notifications against
>     the JTA transaction.